# ArchUnit / test architecture for Flutter or Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test, clean-architecture, archunit

I'm developing an Flutter App using Clean Architecture. Now i'm looking for a library or something else like ArchUnit. To test the architecture and to ensure the correct access of packages.

How do you solve the problem and ensure compliance with the architecture. I would appreciate ideas or alternatives.

Comment: Hi have you found any answer to this?

Comment: No, unfortunately not :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not found an Architest equivalent.
Another way to ensure correct access to packages is to use a linter like the following

```
analyzer:
    plugins:
        - import_lint

import_lint:
    rules:
        use_case_rule:
            target_file_path: "/**/use_case/*_use_case.dart"
            not_allow_imports: ["/**/use_case/*_use_case.dart"]
            exclude_imports: ["/**/use_case/base_use_case.dart"]
```

https://github.com/kawa1214/import-lint